# site redirect sometimes malfunctions

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a wordpress blog and don't want others to visit it. So I moved the blog to **http://myhost.com/wordpress**(sorry for hiding the name) and put an index.php in the root folder of **http://myhost.com**.

The index.php is simply random redirecting:

```
<?php
$sites = array("http://google.com", "http://youtube.com", "http://facebook.com", "http://twitter.com")
$len = count($sites);
$num = rand(0, $len - 1);
$str = "Location:".$sites[$num];
header($str);
?>
```

But sometimes (usually when the network is slow) when I visit **http:/myhost.com/wordpress** it redirects me to one of these sites I set. This also happens when I click links in the wordpress.

I cannot even identify whether it's browser's action or the server's.

Comment: you should have a exit after the header it its not the last line in the script.

Comment: could condense the above to: header($sites[array_rand($sites)]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because Wordpress's default action on 404 is to redirect to your main index.php

If you have access, you can change this in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Because you change directory of your Wordpress files but you don't change database datas. You have to change your WOrdpress blog URL from **http://myhost.com/** to **http://myhost.com/wordpress** on wp-admin, (Settings > General section) .

If you can't login to your admin panel, you have to execute these SQL queries :
(don't forget to edit site URL and Wordpress table prefix (wp) !)

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='http://myhost.com/wordpress' WHERE option_name='siteurl'
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='http://myhost.com/wordpress' WHERE option_name='home'
```

Wordpress gets home url from database. Your database pointing home url to **http://myhost.com/** . When you click **Home Page** link it will go to home url (**http://myhost.com/**)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I can log in to wp and usually everything is ok.